# Parse only one item from RSS feed with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I'm trying to parse just one item form a rss feed. Basically, I'm trying to get the newest/last item from the rss feed and not parse the whole feed. Right now I have this code:

```
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++)
{
$item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
```

However, this loops through all the items. I don't need all the elements/items. I just need the newest/last item on the feed. How can I achieve this? Would the following code work?

```
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$item_title=$x->item->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_link=$x->item->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_desc=$x->item->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: typo in the second version: getElement(s)ByTagName (missing the S).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out:

```
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
$item_title=$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_link=$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('link')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_desc=$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('description')
->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```